# Android test for a table in sql database

Tags: android, sql, database

how can I query whether a certain table already exists in an SQL database and if it doesn't already exist, it should be created?
I create a Table and Database like this:

```
databaseClasses = getBaseContext().openOrCreateDatabase(databaseName_Login, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
databaseClasses.execSQL("CREATE TABLE classes(clas TEXT, password TEXT, email TEXT)");
databaseClasses.close();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just add `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS classes(clas TEXT, password TEXT, email TEXT)` ?

Comment: I didn't know that, but Thanks!

Comment: No worries, that was straight from the [sqlite documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) A nifty feature to avoid errors and cross checks.